# unable to access rootscope var in directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

The function below defines a variable in the rootscope.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.buttons = [{href: '#/students', icon:'icon-ok'},
                         {href: '#/students', icon:'icon-remove'},
                         {href: '#/students/new', icon:'icon-plus'}];
}
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
```

The html in the directive below depends upon a variable in the rootscope -

```
angular.module('btnbar.directive', []).
directive("btnBar", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope :{},
    controller: function($scope, $element,$rootScope) {
    },
    template:'<div class="btn-toolbar">' +
      '<a class="btn" ng-repeat="b in buttons" href={{b.href}}>' +
      '<i class={{b.icon}}></i></a></div>',
    replace:true
  }
});
```

However the above code doesnt work. It works if I directly define the 'buttons' var in the directive scope.

Answer (score 23):

You have an **isolate** scope in your directive

```
scope:{}
```

This means that the directive doesn't have access to upper scopes - remember that isolate scopes don't prototypically inherit from the parent scope. So you either remove the isolate scope or tell the directive to bind some properties to its local scope from the parent scope.

```
scope: {buttons: '='}
```

Then invoke the directive like this

```
<btn-bar buttons="buttons"></btn-bar>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/88R66L7uAHoezDZvuoH5?p=preview

---

Also, rather than modifying the `$rootScope` from a controller, you might want to do it from the `run` method

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['btnbar.directive']);

app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.buttons = [{href: '#/students', icon:'icon-ok'},
                        {href: '#/students', icon:'icon-remove'},
                        {href: '#/students/new', icon:'icon-plus'}];
});
```

Comment: Jim thanks for the great reply. One question why do I need to specify the buttons = "buttons" in my attribute. Also what does it do ? Why wont the code work without the above attribute declaration ?

Comment: because the directive controller accept scope,element,attribute and transclude, ur third parameter is $rootScope which is actually the attribute parameter. here is ur controller code:
 function($scope, $element,$rootScope) .
 Now see the documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @AsadYarKhan I think you're confusing controller with link and compile.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

`<a class="btn" ng-repeat="b in $root.buttons" href={{b.href}}>`

Comment: This answer make more sense considering the title of the question