# Why can't the $rootScope be accessed in the template of a directive with isolate scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

With isolate scope the template of the directive does not seem to be able to access the controller ('Ctrl') $rootScope variable which, however, does appear in the controller of the directive. I understand why the controller ('Ctrl') $scope variable isn't visible in the isolate scope.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <my-template></my-template>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
        <label ng-click="test(blah)">Click</label>
    </script>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl1($scope,  $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.blah = 'Hello';
        $scope.yah = 'World'
    })
    .directive('myTemplate', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
            scope: {},
            controller: ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope) {
                console.log($rootScope.blah);
                console.log($scope.yah);,

                $scope.test = function(arg) {
                    console.log(arg);
                }
            }]
        };
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg74b/18/)

The variable is accessed with no isolate scope - as can be seen by commenting the isolate scope line:

```
        // scope: {},
```

Comment: Have you tried injecting $rootScope into the directive ... `directive('myTemplate', function($rootScope) { ... })` ?

Comment: @MarcKline Just tried that and no luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895124/unable-to-access-rootscope-var-in-directive-scope

Comment: Is there a reason why using a service is not sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: @MarcKline I'm starting to think you may be right and a service is the best way to go.

Comment: camden_kid or Marc (or any one reading this), Can you specify the advantages of one approach over other ($root vs Factory approach I mean)? Why is using factory better?

Comment: @Kalyan - I personally think $rootScope should only be used for events and Factory for passing data to directives. One reason is that using $rootScope is like using global variables which isn't ideal. Also, a Factory can be a well defined wrapper which can be extended at a later date.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can try this way out using `$root.blah`

**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/mg74b/24/)**

**html**

```
 <label ng-click="test($root.blah)">Click</label>
```

**javascript**

```
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl1($scope,  $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.blah = 'Hello';
        $scope.yah = 'World'
    })
    .directive('myTemplate', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
            scope: {},
            controller: ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope) {
                console.log($rootScope.blah);
                console.log($scope.yah);

                $scope.test = function(arg) {
                    console.log(arg);
                }
            }]
        };
    });
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it 'solves' what I wanted to achieve (I didn't know of '$root' or that it could be used like this). **However**, I would suggest that Mark Kline's answer is generally the best solution.

Comment: amazing! its quite useful to know that the $rootScope changes into $root into the views, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is perfect since what I needed to do was accessing a function defined in the rootScope

Comment: Good one. It's working here too. Can you please explain why $root instead of $rootScope? I have also injected $rootScope but it is undefined while function call.

Answer (score 32):

Generally, you should avoid using `$rootScope` to store values you need to share between controllers and directives. It's like using globals in JS. Use a service instead:

**A constant (or value ... use is similar):**

```
.constant('blah', 'blah')
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module

**A factory (or service or provider):**

```
.factory('BlahFactory', function() {
    var blah = {
        value: 'blah'
    };

    blah.setValue = function(val) {
      this.value = val;
    };

    blah.getValue = function() {
        return this.value;
    };

    return blah;
})
```

Here is a [fork of your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/FVspE/) demonstrating how you might use either

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for this and for pointing me in the **correct** direction for what I am trying to achieve. I think NidhishKrishnan's should be accepted as the 'answer' for the reason stated in my comment.

Comment: +1 for the use case of constants as they are rare to be used. Also the note on not using $rootScope was a pro tip.

Answer (score 23):

1) Because of the isolate scope `$scope` in your controller Ctrl and in the directive controller don't refer to the same scope - let's says we have *scope1* in Ctrl and *scope2* in directive.

2) Because of the isolate scope *scope2* **do not** prototypicallly inherit from `$rootScope` ; so if you define `$rootScope.blah` there is no chance you can see it in *scope2*.

3) What you can access in your directive template is *scope2*

If I sum it up, here is the inheritance schema

```
    _______|______
    |            |
    V            V
$rootScope     scope2
    |
    V
  scope1


$rootScope.blah
> "Hello"
scope1.blah
> "Hello"
scope2.blah
> undefined
```

Comment: Very helpful but nidhishkrishnan's workaround does work if somehow using rootScope values is necessary. A nice hack it is.

Comment: Well, what you said is logic in order to answer why I can't use $rootScope variables in html (without $root.), but when I use the Batarang plug-in to see the $scopes, I can clearly see that $rootScope is the parent $scope of all the others (including isolated scope in directives). Also, the definition from the angular official docs said: "Every application has a single root scope. All other scopes are descendant scopes of the root scope"
(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question. But it didn't satisfy my inquisition about why the isolated scope won't be able to access properties in the $rootscope.

So I dug in the angular lib and found -

```
$new: function(isolate) {
  var ChildScope,
      child;

  if (isolate) {
    child = new Scope();
    child.$root = this.$root;
    child.$$asyncQueue = this.$$asyncQueue;
    child.$$postDigestQueue = this.$$postDigestQueue;
  } else {

    if (!this.$$childScopeClass) {
      this.$$childScopeClass = function() {
        // blah blah...
      };
      this.$$childScopeClass.prototype = this;
    }
    child = new this.$$childScopeClass();
  }
```

This is the function called by angular whenever a new scope is created. Here it's clear that any isolated scope is not prototypically inheriting the rootscope. rather only the rootscope is added as a property '$root' in the new scope. So we can only access the properties of rootscope from the $root property in the new isolated scope.