# how to display rootScope on html page for testing?

Tags: angularjs

I am starting with angular js and was trying to display the rootscope like this on my view:

```
{{rootScope | json}}
```

It says $SCOPE , how can I display the contents of the rootscope on the page?

Comment: This feels like an XY question.  Using `$rootScope` is rarely if ever necessary.  Beyond that, what are you expecting to see in the `$rootScope` object, except the child `$scope` objects?

Comment: I am using the rootscope because  I build a wizard type dialogue and passing on data through the rootsope variable

Comment: *Don't do that*.  Use a service.  `$rootScope` is not designed to be a global object dumping ground.

Comment: Why not use a rootscope? Stil interested in how to display it anyway .

Comment: Well, aside from your question not making any sense, you clearly don't understand how scopes work in angular.  "Why not use a rootscope?"  - Because there is only a single `$rootScope` in the document, which all `$scope` inherit from.  in order to show the `$rootScope` in HTML, it would have to be a property on the current `$scope` bound to that HTML, which would be a circular reference.  I'm not sure what the code you posted even is, because `rootScope` **is not** `$rootScope`.

Comment: Like I said I am just starting with angular relax dude take a chill pill.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595866/why-cant-the-rootscope-be-accessed-in-the-template-of-a-directive-with-isolate) might be helpful. I don't know how to print the entire rootscope in HTML but you can display parts using `{{$root.yourKey}}`. I use the [Chrome console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and it works with the entire rootscope. To view it, Press: Chrome Menu > More Tools > JavaScript Console. Then just do this in your controller: `console.log($rootScope);` and make sure to inject `$rootScope` also.

Comment: Thanks adrian for your input